# create child using mkdir with variable

Tags: mkdir

I have the path `/home/folder/test` set as variable `$1`

I want to make a directory using mkdir, I think, that will be in a new folder but has the same name as the last child folder.  So for example I want to make a folder called `/home/folder2/test`.

Is this something that I should be using xargs for?  I'm not too experience with shell commands, so I'm pretty confused how to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a UNIX-like operating system, if you have a string `/home/folder/test` and you want the last part of it, you can simply use `basename` to get that:

```
pax> str="/home/folder/test"
pax> base="$(basename $str)"
pax> echo "${base}"
test
```

Once you have that, you can use it to make another directory:

```
pax> mkdir -p "/home/folder2/${base}"
pax> ls -al "/home/folder2/test"
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 pax pax  6 Apr  2 04:19 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 pax pax 49 Apr  2 04:19 ..
```